# when setting up active directory do I need to use a domain such as egglighting.com or can i just do something like EGG.DNS

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

Im setting up a  new AD configuration in my work due to them previously not having one.
I can get the intiial install of ad and promote it to a domain controller just fine I am jsut wondering how the Root domain should be set up. Should I do it with a domain and dns server built in or use my router that I already have for the dns or the google dns server.

I plan to have it set up in a way that allows me to create accounts in the on premise AD and have it sync with My exchange and azure Active directory server.

Any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use an unused sub-domain of the domain name your company owns, such as ad.mycompany.com.

Comment: THis shouldnt affect the netbio or that correct?

Comment: What about the dns server?

Comment: The DNS server role will be installed when you promote the server to a Domain Controller. Use the DNS role on the server for the AD DNS zone.

Comment: alright so I will just use the TLD then as it appears to not need too much modification